# how to delete rows of a table if they contain values from select query of another table?

Tags: mysql

what would be the query to delete rows of a table where they contain values from select query of another table? I tried using exist(select query) but it erased all entries.

ok so I need to select rows that include a text from a column in a table, get the product id(another column) from that table same table, and then delete rows that include this id from another table(products table)

Comment: Post more information about your table structure or sample data or expected result, just more please.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information in question:

As per my understanding your question you can use syntax as

DELETE FROM tablename WHERE columnname IN (...your select query...)

Now you just have a WHERE with no comparison:

DELETE FROM tablename WHERE (...your select query...)

Comment: ok so I need to selecct rows that include a text from a column in a table, get the product id(another column) from that table same table, and then delete rows that include this id from another table(products table)

Comment: please try.

else give some more detail about your table structure so that i can get more idea.